# Ending nested message loop of a custom dialog

Tags: c++, winapi

I have a dialog class made from dialog template in memory which runs it's own nested message loop (in addition to main app msg loop).

To create a dialog I use `CreateDialogIndirectParamW` which returns handle to the dialog window,

Since the dialog is completely customized, all the message processing and creation is done manually.

I omitted Dialog procedure, but basically it calls the below relevant message handlers, once the the dialog is closing down.

Note that, we can't use `EndDialog` function to destroy the dialog and end message loop because for `CreateDialogIndirectParamW` we must use `DestroyWindow` explicitly.

I'm looking for efficient way to end the dialog loop.

I tried to implement [this loop](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/348/Implementing-Modal-Message-Loops) but problem is that this approach will either consume too much CPU resources since the `for` loop in the sample code will just run silly until there is a message, or if `for` is omited then `PeekMessage` will stop the loop immediately, which is not what I wan't.

**Relevant class declaration:**

```
class Dialog :
    public ContainerWindow,
    public MessageWindow,
    public SuperClassWindow
{
    // ...

public:
    /** Process messages for dialog window */
    [[nodiscard]] int RunMessageLoop() override;

protected:
    /** Handler for WM_NCDESTROY */
    std::uint32_t OnNcDestroy(const UINT& uMsg, const WPARAM& wParam, const LPARAM& lParam) override;

    /** Handler for WM_DESTROY */
    inline void OnDestroy() const noexcept override;

    /** Handler for WM_CLOSE */
    inline virtual bool OnClose() noexcept;

    // ...

protected:
        HWND mhWnd;                 /** Window handle of derived component */
    }
```

**Simplified class definition:**

```
std::uint32_t Dialog::OnNcDestroy(
    [[maybe_unused]] const UINT& uMsg,
    [[maybe_unused]] const WPARAM& wParam,
    [[maybe_unused]] const LPARAM& lParam)
{
    // ...
    delete this; // note we can't set this pointer to nullptr!
    // ...
    return count;
}

void Dialog::OnDestroy() const noexcept
{
    PostQuitMessage(0);
}

bool Dialog::OnClose() noexcept
{
    return DestroyWindow(mhWnd);
}
```

And here is the **message loop** for a dialog:
I need to add some checking code into the loop to check if dialog is valid object, that is stop the loop somehow if the Dialog object has been deleted

Once the `OnNcDestroy` handler is called, `IsDialogMessageW` bellow will fail, see comment.

Looks like `GetMessageW` will continue running after `WM_NCDESTROY` is dispatched, the loop is still waiting for `WM_QUIT` sent by `OnDestroy` handler so the msg loop will continue running once the Dialog object is deleted, and that will make `IsDialogMessageW(mhWnd, &msg)` bellow fail. since `mhWnd` does not exist any more.

```
int Dialog::RunMessageLoop()
{
    EnableWindow(mhWndParent, FALSE);

    MSG msg{ };
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    while ((result = GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) != FALSE)
    {
        if (result == -1)
        {
            ShowError(ERR_BOILER); // error checking function.
            break;
        }

        // once OnNcDestroy is called "mhWnd" is invalid memory
        // and this will off course cause access violation!
        if (!IsDialogMessageW(mhWnd, &msg))
        {
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }

    EnableWindow(mhWndParent, TRUE);

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}
```

note that we can't `if (this)` because `this` is not `nullptr` and can't be set to `nullptr` in `OnNcDestroy` handler.

Comment: why you not use `DialogBoxIndirectParam` ? and loop example on codeproject.com not take too much CPU resources - here no spin

Comment: @RbMm `DialogBoxIndirectParam` already creates dialog controls defined in dialog template (which I do not define), and does not give you a handle to the dialog, but I need to add custom controls to dialog after it has been created, to make this possible we need `CreateDialogIndirectParam` instead which returns a handle which you can then use as parent handle to initialize your controls. indeed the sample code from codeproject.com spikes the CPU to 27%, here on my 4.6 GHz cpu. (edit: maybe because I make no use of `WaitMessage()` from the sample, ti doesn't explain what it does)

Comment: *but I need to add custom controls to dialog after it has been created* - you can and must do this on `WM_INITDIALOG`. so use `DialogBoxIndirectParam` ok here. *maybe because I make no use of WaitMessage() from the sample* - but this is of course all change.

Comment: in `WM_INITDIALOG` yes, didn't know that thanks! but there is still a difference, for example your solution with `DialogBoxIndirectParam ` implies that dialog procedure is open source or otherwise available for edit, doing it outside the procedure seems to be more flexible for the library I'm working on. since all that user needs to do is call some "attach_control" method on a dialog. I'm just reading the `WaitMessage()` didn't know it's WINAPI function lol, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

OK, after some time experimenting I come out with the following change to the code which makes everything works as it should! (see comments for more info)

btw. I will leave this question open, hopefully there is more efficient way for this, currently `IsWindow` is called for every message which is maybe a performance issue.

```
int Dialog::RunMessageLoop()
{
    EnableWindow(mhWndParent, FALSE);

    MSG msg{ };
    BOOL result = FALSE;

    // first we save the handle to the window
    HWND hwnd = mhWnd;
    if (!IsWindow(hwnd)) // make sure the handle is valid dialog window
        std::abort();

    while ((result = GetMessageW(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0)) != FALSE)
    {
        if (result == -1)
        {
            ShowError(ERR_BOILER);
            break;
        }

        // if object is deleted the handle is no longer valid!
        // because prior to OnNcDestroy handler DestroyWindow has been called
        if (!IsWindow(hwnd))
            goto invalid;

        if (!IsDialogMessageW(mhWnd, &msg))
        {
        invalid: // non dialog message processing
            TranslateMessage(&msg);
            DispatchMessageW(&msg);
        }
    }

    // NOTE that we removed EnableWindow(mHwndParent) here!

    return static_cast<int>(msg.wParam);
}
```

This on it's own will work but one additional step is to enable owner window (main window) before the dialog is destroyed, so update the handler:

```
bool Dialog::OnClose() noexcept
{
    // otherwise first window in Z order (such as Desktop) will get focus!
    EnableWindow(mhWndParent, TRUE); 

    return DestroyWindow(mhWnd);
}
```